# Jquery Validation Multiple Email with ";" separator.?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to write my mail addresses for one input.

But my input thrown "invalid email" error when I write ";" separator. Can anyone help me with this?

myCodes

```
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" name="toMail" id="toMail" type="email" />
                    </div>

rules: {
        toMail: { required: true, multiemails: true },
    },
    messages: {
        toMail: {
            required: "Bu alan zorunludur. *",
            multiemails: "Uygun bir email girin !"
        },
    },


jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "multiemails",
    function (value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element
            return true;
        var emails = value.split(/[;,]+/); // split element by , and ;
        valid = true;
        for (var i in emails) {
            value = emails[i];
            valid = valid &&
                jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
        }
        return valid;
    },

    jQuery.validator.messages.multiemails
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not set your input for multiple emails. You need to set `multiple` attribute, check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email):

> If and only if the multiple attribute is specified, the value can be a
> list of properly-formed comma-separated e-mail addresses. Any trailing
> and leading whitespace is removed from each address in the list.

Example:

```
<input id="emailAddress" type="email" multiple>
```